# How to convert list to string[]

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a List as following

```
List<string> email = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ToList<string>();
```

**filename** is text I `openFileDialog`. The text in file txt is 3 line with 3 gmail
I want convert List to

```
string[] arRcpt = new string[] {  };
```

Comment: The File.ReadAllLines() itself returns a string[].

Comment: In addition, you can always use `ToArray` method.

Comment: However, if for some reason you do need to cast it to list first, you can always convert it back to array with `email.ToArray()`. [Check the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.toarray?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `File.ReadAllLines(fileName)` returns a string[]. You don't need to convert it into a list and then to string[]. You can directly assign it to an array.

```
string[] arRcpt = File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
```